# Group pageviews into sessions using timestamp difference

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, sessionid, pageviews

I have a table with 3 fields: user_id, page and timestamp, looking like this:

```
user_id     page        timestamp
1234567     home.all    2018-03-01 00:10
7541231     task.now    2018-03-01 03:51
7541231     home.all    2018-03-01 03:53
4544731     talk.wow    2018-03-01 04:56
4544731     task.now    2018-03-01 05:01
4544731     home.all    2018-03-01 05:02
4544731     bla.home    2018-03-01 05:26
4544731     home.all    2018-03-01 06:40
```

Timestamp is the time when a user with a given ID loaded a given page on a website. Each observation is a pageview hit.

I need to assign a *session ID* for each observation. Each session id should be unique for each session, where a session is a group of pageviews, where the closest to each other timestamps have time difference no more than *3600 seconds*, occured from the *same user_id*.

The result should look like this:

```
user_id     page        timestamp           session_id
1234567     home.all    2018-03-01 00:10    1234567-2018030100100010
7541231     task.now    2018-03-01 03:51    7541231-2018030103510353
7541231     home.all    2018-03-01 03:53    7541231-2018030103510353
4544731     talk.wow    2018-03-01 04:56    4544731-2018030104560526
4544731     task.now    2018-03-01 05:01    4544731-2018030104560526
4544731     home.all    2018-03-01 05:02    4544731-2018030104560526
4544731     bla.home    2018-03-01 05:26    4544731-2018030104560526
4544731     home.all    2018-03-01 06:40    4544731-2018030106400640
```

Could you, please, suggest any query for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure that the pair of `user_id` and `timestamp` is unique, the following might work for you.

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT h1.user_id,
       h1.page,
       h1.timestamp,
       coalesce(h1.timestamp - h2.timestamp <= INTERVAL '3600 SECONDS', false) shares_session_with_previous,
       coalesce(h4.timestamp - h1.timestamp <= INTERVAL '3600 SECONDS', false) shares_session_with_next
       FROM hit h1
            LEFT JOIN hit h2
                      ON h2.user_id = h1.user_id
                         AND h2.timestamp = (SELECT max(h3.timestamp)
                                                    FROM hit h3
                                                    WHERE h3.user_id = h1.user_id
                                                          AND h3.timestamp < h1.timestamp)
            LEFT JOIN hit h4
                      ON h4.user_id = h1.user_id
                         AND h4.timestamp = (SELECT min(h5.timestamp)
                                                    FROM hit h5
                                                    WHERE h5.user_id = h1.user_id
                                                          AND h5.timestamp > h1.timestamp)
)
SELECT c1.user_id,
       c1.page,
       c1.timestamp,
       concat((SELECT concat(c2.user_id, '-', to_char(max(c2.timestamp), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'))
                      FROM cte c2
                      WHERE c2.user_id = c1.user_id
                            AND c2.timestamp <= c1.timestamp
                            AND NOT c2.shares_session_with_previous
                      GROUP BY c2.user_id),
              (SELECT to_char(min(c2.timestamp), 'HH24MI')
                      FROM cte c2
                      WHERE c2.user_id = c1.user_id
                            AND c2.timestamp >= c1.timestamp
                            AND NOT c2.shares_session_with_next)) session_id
       FROM cte c1
       ORDER BY c1.timestamp;
```

The core part is the CTE. For each row the row with the youngest older timestamp and the row with the oldest younger timestamp is joined. The interval between the older or the youngest timestamp and the timestamp of the row is checked to be less than or equal 3600 seconds. The result of that checks are stored in the flags `shares_session_with_previous` and `shares_session_with_next`.

The flags are then used to get the begin and the end of a session. A begin is the youngest timestamp older than or equal the current timestamp where `shares_session_with_previous` is `false`. An end is the oldest timestamp younger than or equal the current timestamp where `shares_session_with_next` is `false`.

The respective values from the begin and the end of the session are concatenated to give your session id.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ac9d44/62)